# Open compactification of metric space

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, compactness

Suppose I have a separable metric space $X$. I wanted to ask if there exists a separable metric compactification of this space $\overline{X}$, s.t. $X$ is considered open in $\overline{X}$.

Comment: What about the [Alexandroff extension](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alexandroff_extension#The_Alexandroff_extension)? I'm not entirely sure that there always is a way to extend the metric to the compactification, though.

Comment: I forgot to mention I need the compactification to be metric

Comment: [This](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/62820/metrizable-compactifications) question might be relevant.

Comment: Yes, thank you. I noticed a few things and changed my question accordingly

Comment: Do you require the metric on $\overline X$ to be an extension of the given metric on $X$?

Comment: Yes it should be an extension

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is possible iff $X$ is also locally compact.

---

Let $\beta X$ denote the Stone-Cech compactification of $X$. The following lemmas are standard.

**Lemma.** $X$ is open in $\beta X$ iff $X$ is locally compact.

**Lemma.** If $\gamma X$ is a compactification of $X$, then there is a continuous surjection $f:\beta X\to\gamma X$ such that $f[X]=X$ and $f[\beta X\setminus X]=\gamma X\setminus X$.

It easily follows that:

**Theorem.**

(1) If $X$ is open in *some* compactification, then $X$ is locally compact.

(2) If $X$ is locally compact, then $X$ is open in *every* compactification.

---

Back to your question...

By (1), locally compact is necessary. So $\mathbb Q$, for instance, would be a counterexample. (Actually, if $\gamma \mathbb Q$ is a compactification of $\mathbb Q$, then $\mathbb Q$ *contains no open subset of* $\gamma \mathbb Q$!)

Now let $X$ be separable metric and  locally compact. As $X$ is separable metric, it embeds into the Hilbert cube $[0,1]^\omega$. The closure of $X$ in this cube is a separable metric compactification, and $X$ is open in it by (2).