# Induced topology by a complete uniform space.

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, compactness

I know that [Uniform space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_space) is generalization idea of metric space,Uniform space like metric space induce a topological space.

Now my question is ( or are ):-
In case our Uniform space was complete ,what will be added to the induced topology, more specifically We know that Complete metric space induce [paracompact](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paracompact_space) topological space. 
Does Also this true for Uniform Space? that if the uniform space are complete are the topology space induced by the uniform space will be paracompact?

Remark:- A uniform space $X$ is complete if every Cauchy net/filter in $X$ converges (not necessarily to a unique point).

Comment: All metric spaces, not just the complete ones, are paracompact.

Comment: http://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1977-062-02/S0002-9939-1977-0436085-3/S0002-9939-1977-0436085-3.pdf seems relevant. It gives a condition for uniform spaces to be paracompact.

Comment: Also: http://math.stackexchange.com/a/154119/4280

Comment: In the second link you put they are proving "Every paracompact Hausdorff space is completely uniformizable ".

Comment: Yes, but you asked for the reverse, right?

Comment: Sorry, I just want to say, they are proving the stronger version of it, I mean, in my case the space is not necessary Hausdorff.

Comment: more precisely,Can the Paracompact space admit a compatible complete unifomty ?

Comment: Normally, uniform spaces are assumed to be $T_0$ (and then they are Tychonoff), and paracompact spaces are assumed to be Hausdorff (and thus normal). Inspect the proofs if the assumptions are necessary, if you're interested in the more general case.

Comment: And if we had a non-normal Tychonoff space that admitted a complete uniformity, we'd have a counterexample. Maybe the Tychonoff plank?

Comment: You mean deleted Tychonff plank?

Comment: It's also known by that name, yes.

Comment: "the Encyclopedia of General Topology By K.P. Hart, Jun-iti Nagata, J.E" said Tychnoff plank is nether countable compact nor normal. So in this case its our counter example. can you please make your comments as an answer I am sure , people get this useful.

Comment: It's only a counter example if it admits a *complete* uniformity