# Existence of an homeomorphism between $X$ a complete separable metric space and a subspace of $[0,1]^{\mathbb{N}}$

Tags: probability, general-topology, measure-theory, reference-request, metric-spaces

**Result:** If $X$ is a complete separable metric space  then there is  a $E \subset [0,1]^{\mathbb{N}}$ such that $X$ is homeomorphic to $E$  ($E$ is a $G_\delta$ set - is the intersection of denumerable open sets)

This result is used to prove theorem 2.3 of  [PARTHASARATHY, 1967, Probability measures on metric spaces, [pg 18](https://books.google.sk/books?id=PJPiBQAAQBAJ&pg=PA8)]. and it is quoted as a well know result.

1) How to prove this result?

This result is to be found (according the author) in Kuratowski's 1933 book "Topologie I" pages 215-216. But I couldn't find it.

2) Could you indicate a good book where this result is to be found?

Comment: You can find some questions on this site which are closely related. For example: [Polish Spaces and the Hilbert Cube](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/19344/polish-spaces-and-the-hilbert-cube), [Urysohn's metrization theorem and Borel image](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/263127/urysohns-metrization-theorem-and-borel-image).

Comment: If you simple google for some reasonable phrases (like ["hilbert cube" separable metric](https://books.google.com/books?q="hilbert+cube"+separable+metric) or
[separable metric embedded](https://books.google.com/books?q=separable+metric+embedded)) you might be able to find a few references by yourself.