# Is the cardinality of uncountable $G_{\delta}$ set of $\mathbb{R}$ equals the cardinality of the continuum?

Tags: cardinals, descriptive-set-theory

It is known that closed sets of $\mathbb{R}$ satisfies continuum hypothesis, that is, every closed subset of $\mathbb{R}$ is either countable or of the cardinality of
the continuum.

Is the cardinality of uncountable $G_{\delta}$ set of $\mathbb{R}$ equals the cardinality of the continuum?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes. In fact the cardinality of every Borel set is countable or size continuum.

There is an easy proof for $G_\delta$. Every $G_\delta$ set is completely metrizable, and therefore either countable or contains a perfect set (which has a copy of a Cantor space).

(See [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/19345/622) for the former fact, and the [Cantor-Bendixson derivative](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derived_set_%28mathematics%29), and related theorems for the latter)