# Define a metric on $G_\delta$ set making it complete

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, metric-spaces

A subset $A$ is a $G_{\delta}$ subset if $A=\bigcap_{1}^{\infty} G_i$ is a countable intersection of open sets $\{ G_i \}$. Show that in metric space $(X,d)$, every closed set is a $G_\delta$ set. If $A$ is a $G_\delta$ subset of a complete metric space $(X,d)$ show that there is metric $D$ on $A$ that induces the same convergence as $d$ on $A$, but $(A,D)$ is complete.

For the first part of the question, I take a closed set $C$, define $d(x,C)=\inf\{d(x,b):b\in C\}$, then let $G_k=\{x\in X: d(x,C)<\frac{1}{k}\}$, prove $G_k$ is open and $C=\bigcap G_k$. But to the second part, I really don't know where to start. My professor showed in his lecture notes that, if $O$ is an open set in $(X,d)$, define $D(x,y)=d(x,y)+|\frac{1}{d(x,O^C)}-\frac{1}{d(y,O^C)}|$, then $(O,D)$ is complete. I understand why this works. But in a $G_\delta$ set $A$, $A$ could be closed, and I have difficulty defining metric at the boundary. I tried $D(x,y)=\begin{cases} d(x,y)+|\frac{1}{d(x,O^C)}-\frac{1}{d(y,O^C)}| &\quad d(x,O^C)\cdot d(y,O^C) \neq 0\\d(x,y) &\quad otherwise \end{cases}$, but it seems to fail that it doesn't satisfy triangular inequality. Any hint for this? Thank you!

Comment: Can you embed $\bigcap O_n$ into $\prod O_n$ (as a closed subspace)?

Comment: @DanielFischer Sorry I don't know much about Topology. Could you explain more? Thank you

Comment: See also this: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/19344/polish-spaces-and-the-hilbert-cube/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Presumably you know how to define a metric on a product of countably many (nonempty) metric spaces that induces the product topology, and that makes the product a complete metric space if all factors are complete.

Thus, if we have a $G_{\delta}$ set

$$A = \bigcap_{n \in \mathbb{N}} O_n,$$

since you know how to define a metric on each $O_n$ that makes it complete and induces the subspace topology, you can define a metric $d_P$ on

$$P = \prod_{n\in \mathbb{N}} O_n$$

that induces the product topology and makes $P$ complete. The product topology on $P$ coincides with the subspace topology induced from $X^{\mathbb{N}}$. In $X^{\mathbb{N}}$ we consider the diagonal

$$\Delta = \bigl\{ f \in X^{\mathbb{N}} : \bigl(\forall k,n\bigr)\bigl(f(k) = f(n)\bigr)\bigr\}.$$

$\Delta$ is easily seen to be closed in $X^{\mathbb{N}}$, hence

$$B = P \cap \Delta$$

is a (relatively) closed subspace of $P$. Hence $(B,d_P\lvert_{B\times B})$ is a complete metric space.

Now note that the diagonal map $\delta \colon x \mapsto c_x$, where $c_x(n) = x$ for all $n\in \mathbb{N}$ is a homeomorphism between $A$ and $B$. Hence $d_A \colon (x,y) \mapsto d_P(\delta(x),\delta(y))$ is a metric on $A$ that induces the subspace topology, and makes $A$ complete.

Comment: Why $\Delta$ is closed in $X^{\mathbb{N}}$?

Comment: At the end of the day it's because metric spaces are Hausdorff. If you have a point $f \in X^{\mathbb{N}}\setminus \Delta$, there are two indices with $f(k) \neq f(n)$. Pick disjoint neighbourhoods $U$ of $f(k)$ and $V$ of $f(n)$, then $\{ g \in X^{\mathbb{N}} : g(k) \in U \text{ and } g(n) \in V\}$ is a neighbourhood of $f$ which doesn't intersect $\Delta$, so the complement of $\Delta$ is open.

Comment: Dear Daniel thanks a lot for your answer!

Comment: Hello, I am reading your post and do not quite understand why do you want to construct the product of open sets from the $G_\delta$ set to construct a complete metric on $B$.  As another answer indicates, $\rho(x,y)$ should be the desired metric to make such a completion, which I understand the intuition. But how can I combine $\rho(x,y)$ to your argument, especially the embedding part? Can you add some details if possible? I am trying to weave the arguments but failed. Thank you!

Comment: @Mike Sorry for the late reply, I got distracted. I use the product because code-reuse saves work. Defining a metric on a countable product of metric spaces that induces the product topology, and such that it is complete if and only if all factors are complete (or if the product is empty) is something that's often needed. Hence we have a general construction (actually, several rather similar standard constructions) that we can reuse, sparing us the pain to do it every time from scratch. One of the standard constructions gives almost the $\rho$ from Henno's answer (a small modification gives

Comment: that $\rho$ exactly). Another often used thing in topology are subspaces. Important facts there are that the product topology and the subspace topology are compatible in the sense that the product topology of subspace topologies is the subspace topology induced from the product topology (product and subspace topologies are initial topologies, and initial topologies have a transitivity property that is the cause for that), and that a subspace of a complete metric space is complete (in the restricted metric) if and only if it is closed.

Comment: And then I use these building blocks. On each $O_n$ we have a metric that makes it complete and induces the subspace topology (see the question body). From these we get a metric on $P = \prod O_n$ that makes it complete and induces the correct topology. Then we look at a closed, hence complete, subspace of $P$, the diagonal. This subspace is essentially $A = \bigcap O_n$, only each point $x$ corresponds to the constant sequence. The diagonal map $\delta$ is continuous because each of its component maps is just the inclusion $A \to O_n$.

Comment: It's an embedding because (it is bijective and) its inverse is just the projection (on an arbitrary factor) restricted to $B$. Thus we get the result by combining much used results from elsewhere. Do you know these building blocks already? If so, I hope you can now understand the construction. If not, I advise you to look at them, as I said they are often used, so knowing them is convenient. And I find the proofs in the abstract easier and more comprehensible than getting distracted by the concrete details here.

Comment: I read your explanation regarding your method, and I think I can understand your approach now. If you think my method is correct, I'll write an answer under this post for a new proof. And my method is inspired by the other author. Thank you!

Comment: @Mike Of course you need to fill in the details (for which there isn't space in a comment), especially the "every Cauchy sequence converges" part needs elaboration, but the idea works.

Answer (score 2):

To extend your teacher's idea:

Let $Y = \cap_n O_n$ be a $G_\delta$ in $(X,d)$ and define as the new metric

$$\rho(x,y) = d(x,y) + \sum_n \frac{1}{2^n}\min(|\frac{1}{d(x, X\setminus O_n)} - \frac{1}{d(y, X\setminus O_n)}|, 1), x,y \in Y$$

and show it is complete using Daniel's idea. The $\frac{1}{2^n}$ and $\min(.,1)$ is to ensure convergence of the series. We essentially embed $X$ as a closed subset of $X \times \mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{N}}$, using the maps $f_n: x \to \frac{1}{d(x,X\setminus O_n)}$.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sketch of the proof for my new ideas:

If $A=\bigcap_{j=1}^{\infty}G_j$, define the metric

$$D(x,y)=d(x,y)+\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2^j}\frac{\left|\frac{1}{d(x,G_j^C)}-\frac{1}{d(y,G_j^C)}\right|}{1+\left|\frac{1}{d(x,G_j^C)}-\frac{1}{d(y,G_j^C)}\right|}$$

Need to show that $(A,D)$ is complete.

On $A$, $D$ and $d$ are equivalent, since if $x_n\to x$, and $x_n$, $x\in G_j$ for every $j$, $$\left|\frac{1}{d(x,G_j^C)}-\frac{1}{d(y,G_j^C)}\right|\to 0$$

then $D(x_n,x)\to 0$. If $D(x_n,x_m)\to 0$, since $d(x_n,x)\to 0$ and $d(x,G_j^C)>0$ for every $j$, this implies $x\in\bigcap_{j=1}^{\infty}G_j=A$.