# $\Bbb Q$ is not complete metrizable.

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why is it that $\mathbb{Q}$ cannot be homeomorphic to *any* complete metric space?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/15710/why-is-it-that-mathbbq-cannot-be-homeomorphic-to-any-complete-metric-spac)

How do you prove that the space of the rational numbers with the usual metric (from the real numbers space) is not complete metrizable?