# Any $V\subset \Bbb R$ is realcompact

Tags: general-topology

> The space $X$ is realcompact if $X$ embeds as a closed subspace into $\Bbb R^\kappa$ for some cardinal $\kappa$.

How can we show that any $V\subset \Bbb R$ is realcompact?

Comment: Doesn't realcompact imply compact? Then your statement is false.

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen A closed set doesn't have to be  bounded. But it's still false because the rationals cannot be homeomorphic to a complete metric space [reference](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/15710/why-is-it-that-mathbbq-cannot-be-homeomorphic-to-any-complete-metric-spac). Maybe it works if he's taking $k$ to be any cardinal number....

Comment: @JSchlather: Thank you, excellent rebound. I'll leave my silly comment so yours won't dangle.

Comment: @JSchlather: Yes, $k$ can be any cardinal.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott All right, I'll admit I didn't see that coming.

Comment: @JSchlather I edited the definition to make this clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way is to show that a Tikhonov space $X$ is realcompact if and only if every $z$-ultrafilter on $X$ with the countable intersection property has non-empty intersection. (A $z$-ultrafilter is an ultrafilter of zero-sets; $Z\subseteq X$ is a zero-set iff there is a continuous $f:X\to[0,1]$ such that $Z=f^{-1}[\{0\}]$. A family $\mathscr{F}$ of sets has the countable intersection property if $\bigcap\mathscr{C}\ne\varnothing$ whenever $\mathscr{C}\subseteq\mathscr{F}$ is countable. This is Theorem $3.11.11$ in R. Engelking, *General Topology*.)

It follow from this that every Lindelöf Tikhonov space is realcompact. $\Bbb R$ is second countable, so it’s hereditarily Lindelöf.