# Why are $\mathbb{Q}$ and $\mathbb{R}\setminus \mathbb{Q}$ not homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}$?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

> Why are $\mathbb{Q}$ and $\mathbb{R}\setminus \mathbb{Q}$ not homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}$?

Does it have something to do with the open sets in $\mathbb{Q}$ and $\mathbb{R}\setminus \mathbb{Q}$ or the density? Or even the cardinality?

Comment: Related: [Why is it that $\Bbb Q$ cannot be homeomorphic to _any_ complete metric space?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/15710/why-is-it-that-mathbbq-cannot-be-homeomorphic-to-any-complete-metric-spac).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since $\mathbb Q$ and $\mathbb R$ do not have the same cardinal, they cannot possibly be homeomorphic.

And $\mathbb R\setminus\mathbb Q$ is not connected. Therefore, it is also not homeomorphic to $\mathbb R$.

Comment: Another approach:  Cauchy sequences always converge in $\mathbb R$ (but not so in the other two spaces).

Comment: @hardmath This is a wrong argument. Cauchy sequences converge in $\mathbb{R}$ but not in $(0,1)$, though both spaces are homemorphic. Metric properties are not preserved by homeomorphisms....

Comment: @EpsilonDelta: Your observation is true, but a correct argument can be based on *local compactness* (as José Carlos Santos pointed out in a now removed Comment) or on the topological property of "being homeomorphic to a complete metric space".

Comment: @hardmath Also, the irrationals are neither locally compact nor $\sigma$-compact. They're very different from the reals.