# There isn't a complete metric over $\mathbb{Q}$ equivalent to the usual metric.

Tags: metric-spaces

I thought about proving this proposition showing that $\mathbb{Q}$ isn't homeomorphic to any Baire spaces, but I'm not sure if this is enough (or even the correct path). Could someone help?

Comment: what does equivalent mean?

Comment: look at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/15710/why-is-it-that-mathbbq-cannot-be-homeomorphic-to-any-complete-metric-spac

Comment: Your suggestion is fine.

Comment: @Timkinsella https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivalence_of_metrics I'm talking about the topological equivalence

Comment: @ChinnapparajR and Gae. S.  thank you!

Answer (score 2):

That is enough. $\mathbb Q$ is a countable union  of nowhere dense sets (namely singletons) so it cannot be complete under any equivalent metric.

Comment: Thank you, Kabo Murphy!